# unloading swf's with embeded flv's, audio keeps playing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

so I have 3 swf's that im loading with buttons into the main swf. The thing is that these 3 external swf's have embeded flv's. when switching between the swf's with the buttons, im using vid1loader.unload();

the only thing is that while the video switched to the other video like it should, the audio keeps running on any number of videos(swf's) that are loaded. My question is how do you stop the audio when using simple Loader and URLRequest to load the swf's?

Answer (score 0):

awesome! I just found the unloadAndStop(); method here:

[Sound keeps playing after external swf was unloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930516/sound-keeps-playing-after-external-swf-was-unloaded)